# Removing Action name from URL and add page title to URL - Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost:17594/Contact/Contact
```

Now I want to show like this:

```
http://localhost:17594/Contact/Contact-us
```

**RouteConfig:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Categories",
        url: "Categories/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Categories", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "FinalKaminet.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Contacts",
        url: "{controller}/{title}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Contact", title = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "FinalKaminet.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional , title = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "FinalKaminet.Controllers" }
    );

}
```

**View**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact" , "Contact" , new { title = "contact-us" } , null)
```

But I got an error in line 63 that use `Categories` map route.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the
> route table matches the supplied values.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 62:       @Html.ActionLink("وبلاگ", "")
>
> Line 63:       @Html.Action("MenuCat" , "Home")

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

Either add a specific route via convention-based routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ContactUs",
    url: "contact/contact-us",
    defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Contact" },
    namespaces: new[] { "FinalKaminet.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional , title = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "FinalKaminet.Controllers" }
);
```

Or enable attribute routing in RouteConfig before convention-based routes

```
//enable attribute routing
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

//other convention-based routes.
routes.MapRoute(....);
```

and apply the route directly to the controller and action.

```
public class ContactController : Controller {

    //GET contact/contact-us
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Contact/Contact-us")]
    public ActionResult Contact() { … }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the url action as Contact-us (to define routes) you could use the Attribute Routing.

```
[Route("Contact/Contact-us")]
    public ActionResult Contact() { … }
```

Refer to the msdn for more information.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your **route config** file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Contacts",
        url: "Contact/{action}/{title}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Contact", title = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "FinalKaminet.Controllers" }
    );
```